# Mex file building with Octave (issue with wrappers)

Tags: c++, octave, wrapper, mex

I am currently porting some code from Matlab to Octave. Some of the functions of the Matlab code use the Piotr's Computer Vision Matlab Toolbox ([here](https://pdollar.github.io/toolbox/)) that includes some mex files.
In Matlab, everything is working like a charm but when I run my codes with Octave, it throws this error:

```
error: 'imResampleMex' undefined near line 50 column 5
```

However all the internal paths within the toolbox should be good. I figured out that the way Matlab and Octave handle mex files is different and tried to build one of the mex files from the C++ function within Octave like this:

```
mkoctfile --mex imResampleMex.cpp
```

It fails and throws the following error messages related to the C++ wrappers function:

```
In file included from imResampleMex.cpp:6:0:
wrappers.hpp:21:24: error: 'wrCalloc' declared as an 'inline' variable
 inline void* wrCalloc( size_t num, size_t size ) { return calloc(num,size);
                        ^
wrappers.hpp:21:24: error: 'size_t' was not declared in this scope
wrappers.hpp:21:36: error: 'size_t' was not declared in this scope
 inline void* wrCalloc( size_t num, size_t size ) { return calloc(num,size);
                                    ^
wrappers.hpp:21:48: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
 inline void* wrCalloc( size_t num, size_t size ) { return calloc(num,size);
                                                ^
wrappers.hpp:21:50: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
 inline void* wrCalloc( size_t num, size_t size ) { return calloc(num,size);
                                                  ^
wrappers.hpp:22:24: error: 'wrMalloc' declared as an 'inline' variable
 inline void* wrMalloc( size_t size ) { return malloc(size); }
                        ^
wrappers.hpp:22:24: error: 'size_t' was not declared in this scope
wrappers.hpp:22:38: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
 inline void* wrMalloc( size_t size ) { return malloc(size); }
                                      ^
wrappers.hpp: In function 'void wrFree(void*)':
wrappers.hpp:23:44: error: 'free' was not declared in this scope
 inline void wrFree( void * ptr ) { free(ptr); }
                                            ^
wrappers.hpp: At global scope:
wrappers.hpp:28:17: error: 'size_t' was not declared in this scope
 void* alMalloc( size_t size, int alignment ) {
                 ^
wrappers.hpp:28:30: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
 void* alMalloc( size_t size, int alignment ) {
                              ^
wrappers.hpp:28:44: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
 void* alMalloc( size_t size, int alignment ) {
                                            ^
wrappers.hpp:28:46: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
 void* alMalloc( size_t size, int alignment ) {
                                              ^
imResampleMex.cpp: In function 'void resampleCoef(int, int, int&, int*&, int*&, T*&, int*, int)':
imResampleMex.cpp:21:39: error: 'alMalloc' cannot be used as a function
   wts = (T*)alMalloc(nMax*sizeof(T),16);
                                       ^
imResampleMex.cpp:22:43: error: 'alMalloc' cannot be used as a function
   yas = (int*)alMalloc(nMax*sizeof(int),16);
                                           ^
imResampleMex.cpp:23:43: error: 'alMalloc' cannot be used as a function
   ybs = (int*)alMalloc(nMax*sizeof(int),16);
                                           ^
imResampleMex.cpp: In function 'void resample(T*, T*, int, int, int, int, int, T)':
imResampleMex.cpp:48:43: error: 'alMalloc' cannot be used as a function
   T *C = (T*) alMalloc((ha+4)*sizeof(T),16); for(y=ha; y<ha+4; y++) C[y]=0;
                                           ^
warning: mkoctfile: building exited with failure status
```

The wrappers.hpp file is looking like this:

```
#ifndef _WRAPPERS_HPP_
#define _WRAPPERS_HPP_
#ifdef MATLAB_MEX_FILE

// wrapper functions if compiling from Matlab
#include "mex.h"
inline void wrError(const char *errormsg) { mexErrMsgTxt(errormsg); }
inline void* wrCalloc( size_t num, size_t size ) { return mxCalloc(num,size); }
inline void* wrMalloc( size_t size ) { return mxMalloc(size); }
inline void wrFree( void * ptr ) { mxFree(ptr); }

#else

// wrapper functions if compiling from C/C++
inline void wrError(const char *errormsg) { throw errormsg; }
inline void* wrCalloc( size_t num, size_t size ) { return calloc(num,size); }
inline void* wrMalloc( size_t size ) { return malloc(size); }
inline void wrFree( void * ptr ) { free(ptr); }

#endif

// platform independent aligned memory allocation (see also alFree)
void* alMalloc( size_t size, int alignment ) {
  const size_t pSize = sizeof(void*), a = alignment-1;
  void *raw = wrMalloc(size + a + pSize);
  void *aligned = (void*) (((size_t) raw + pSize + a) & ~a);
  *(void**) ((size_t) aligned-pSize) = raw;
  return aligned;
}

// platform independent alignned memory de-allocation (see also alMalloc)
void alFree(void* aligned) {
  void* raw = *(void**)((char*)aligned-sizeof(void*));
  wrFree(raw);
}

#endif
```

I imagine I need to modify this file but my knowledge of C++ and of mex files being close to non-existent, I am struggling figuring a way out of this mountain of errors. I don't even have a clue whether I'm going in the right direction or not... Any help is welcome!

**Edit 1:**

I modified my wrappers.hpp file adding `#include <stdlib.h>` to it. A mex file is now created. However, when running the function calling the file, I now get the following error:

```
error: failed to install .mex file function 'imResampleMex'
error: called from
    imResample at line 50 column 4
```

Comment: Maybe Matlab's version of `mex.h` is pulling in some C standard library headers that Octave's version isn't. Try adding `#include <stdlib.h>` in `wrappers.hpp`. That should fix the `size_t` and `free` errors, not sure if it'll fix everything.

Comment: @Praetorian Thank you so much for your input! With this addition a mex file is created now. However, a new error appears when running the function `error: failed to install .mex file function 'imResampleMex'`. I am editing my question right now.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Octave's flavor of mex, so I might not be able to help with this. A Google search suggests something's wrong with your mex file, for instance, `mexFunction` is not being exported correctly? Do you know whether `MATLAB_MEX_FILE` is being defined? Make sure it is, so `mex.h` gets included. Once you define it, you may find that you don't even need to `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: @Praetorian So far, I try to follow this: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Getting-Started-with-Mex_002dFiles.html#Getting-Started-with-Mex_002dFiles
I built the mex file again including `#include "mex.h"`  in the C++ file but still get the same error. I'm not sure I fully understanding what's MATLAB_MEX_FILE. If it's needed for Matlab, then it's defined as I can run my code without any problem there. If it's related to Octave only, do you have a reference (for beginners) that I could read? I only find things about Simulink when reading about it (which is not used in my case)

Comment: Look at the beginning of `wrappers.h`, you'll see `#ifdef` switches based on whether `MATLAB_MEX_FILE` is defined. `mex` defines this symbol automatically, I don't know whether `mkoctfile` does. You should try reverting all changes you've made and try `mkoctfile --mex  -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE imResampleMex.cpp`, that might be all you need to get things to work.

Comment: @Praetorian You are amazing! It works! :) The only thing I was missing from the beginning was `-DMATLAB_MEX_FILE`.

Comment: As a precision, when trying to create another mex file from the same toolbox, I had a similar set of errors even using `mkoctfile --mex -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE the_file.cpp`. Adding `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include "mex.h"` to the `wrappers.hpp` file allowed me to build the mex file properly.

Comment: Well, write an answer explaining what you've learnt so it helps someone else in the future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps I used to solve the issue of creating the mex files from the Piotr's Computer Vision Matlab Toolbox for Octave (concerns the cpp files of the folder `channels` only).

The original mex files that come with the toolbox are built for Matlab and do not work with Octave. While building them from Octave a call is made to the file `wrappers.hpp`.
This file has to be modified by adding these two lines at the beginning of the file: `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include "mex.h"`.

For building the mex file, in the Octave prompt type (while being in the directory of the cpp file):

```
mkoctfile --mex -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE the_file.cpp
```

This way the Octave compatible mex file is created.

Edit 23/05/2017 - After receiving more questions from people having trouble generating these files I released the generated files on Github: https://github.com/Eskapp/Piotr_vision_extrafiles_Octave. Feel free to use them.
You'll need to add them manually to the Computer Vision toolbox.

Comment: Hi @Eskapp I'm now doing exactly the same thing you do. Matlab to Octave with mdp_tracker. After all this mex file problem. still some matlab dependencies problem such as median.m interrupt. I'm just curious if you have a opensource version of those octave code?

Comment: Hey @Pwan, I think I could push them on GitHub. Gonna try. Give me a day or two that I find back these files ;)

Comment: HI Eskapp!!thanks too much too much! Cause I did convert it as well and run the demo. But I think it may still have some bugs inside my code. Your code will help alot. Did you successfully run the demo?

Comment: I only ran the functions I needed for my code to work. I am gonna try to retrieve the files tomorrow. Stay put ;)

Comment: @Pwan https://github.com/Eskapp/Piotr_vision_extrafiles_Octave
You will need to manually add the files to the main toolbox. Let me know if it works. If not, post the error message :)

Comment: Is this the dependencies I need for mdp tracker?

Comment: These are all the files I was able to generate with Octave.

Comment: @Pwan, Just  realized there might have been a misunderstanding between us. mdp tracker is not related to the Piotr's toolbox. Or is it?
What is the error message you get?

Comment: @Eskapp did you managed to get the MDP tracker compilied ? I am also having the same issue. I believe this is what we are trying to compile https://github.com/yuxng/MDP_Tracking

Comment: @Kong I have not worked with the MDP tracker. The scope of the original question was to make the Piotr's toolbox working on Octave. The github repo indicated in the answer provides all files needed for that. Nothing was tested for other libraries.

Comment: @Eskapp okay thank you for the reply. I created a thread at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53322370/issues-running-mex-commands-on-octave in case you want to take a look. I have tried the solutions posted here but am still receiving errors.