# Can not build a mex file in octave using mkoctfile --mex

Tags: matlab, octave, mex

I am trying to build a mex file in octave. The [Octave instructions](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Getting-Started-with-Mex_002dFiles.html) says that we need to use mkoctfile --mex to build one. The file I am trying to build is in the following path:

```
> C:\devwork\Octave\boosted\toolbox\channels\private\rgbConvert.cpp
```

When I write

```
> mkoctfile --mex rgbConvert.cpp
```

I get the following error:

```
> g++: error: rgbConvert.cpp: No such file or directory g++: fatal
> error: no input files compilation terminated.
```

Note: My current directory is set correct. It is at \devwork\Octave\boosted\toolbox\channels\private

Can some one explain me why am I getting this error.

Comment: Can you try compiling with `-I` flag for `mkoctfile` to explicitly include the directory as given [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Getting-Started-with-Oct_002dFiles.html#XREFmkoctfile)?

Comment: Specify the path to the `rgbConvert.cpp` file, not just the filename.

Comment: It seems that you are using the Piotr toolbox. I had trouble using it with Octave a few months back and investigated some issues here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896162/mex-file-building-with-octave-issue-with-wrappers

Comment: Planning on releasing my mex files tonight on GitHub as it seems to be an issue for several people these days.

Comment: On second thought, in we are talking about the Piotr toolbox, the file name that I have in my own folder is `rgbConvertMex.cpp`...

Comment: @Eskapp: I think you should communicate the changes that are necessary to upstream (Piotr) and I'm fairly sure he'll integrate them. So fork the original repo, make your changes and add a pull request

Comment: @Eskapp Yeah, the file was rgbConvertMex.cpp but it wasn't working too. And yes, I'm using Piotr toolbox. I was able to solve my problem with one of the solutions given in your discussion there itself. I had to use `mkoctfile --mex -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE rgbConvertMex.cpp` to create the file. However, it created only .o file under the directory **Private** which even worked. No `.oct` file was created. I just wonder why was `mkoctfile --mex rgbConvertMex.cpp` not working.

Comment: @Eskapp it would be great if you can release the Mex files as Andy suggested. I had to struggle a lot in the conversions. And please do let us know the your GitHub link.

Comment: @Andy Yes, I was exactly looking into doing that. May take a few days as I am a very beginner with Git. I am contacting him today.

Comment: @Sulphur Edit your question and add the changes you made and the new error message you get, so it can help more people :)

Comment: @Sulphur I also only have `.o` files in my folders (no `.oct` files). If I compared my folders to the original ones on `pdollar` repository, I also have extra `.mex` files. It's been months and I forgot the details of how this happen...

Comment: @Sulphur https://github.com/Eskapp/Piotr_vision_extrafiles_Octave
You'll need to manually add the files to the main toolbox and try. Let us know if it helps.

Comment: @Eskapp Thanks :)

Comment: @Eskapp Were you able to use the Pdollar toolbox in octave? I am not able to read video files. I'd be grateful if you can help.

Comment: Yes, I used the Pdollar toolbox in Octave by modifying the wrapper header and generating the `.mex` and `.o` files I provided you. If you do not edit your question and give the exact error you get, it is going to be difficult to help you. A problem for reading video files may not be liked to the toolbox...

Comment: @Eskapp Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44144370/reading-frame-after-converting-matlab-pdollar-toolbox-code-to-octave. .o problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved using: `mkoctfile --mex -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE rgbConvertMex.cpp`

Hence, if you want to convert any Matlab compiled `.mex` file to Octave executable file, do the following two steps:

1. Modify wrappers.hpp file by adding `#include <stdlib.h>`
2. Save the file.
3. Simply run: `mkoctfile --mex -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE file_name`
4. `.o` file will be created.

I did it using the same and it worked fine.

[Eskapp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4762738/eskapp) was grateful enough to release the Octave compiled MEX files. You'll need to manually add the files to the main toolbox.Please find the link here:
https://github.com/Eskapp/Piotr_vision_extrafiles_Octave

Hope it helps others :)

Comment: I'm happy you could make it work and learn something useful at the same time ;)