# Issues running mex commands on Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, mex

I am using Ubuntu and am trying to use Octave to run a Matlab script that runs the mex compiler on some cpp files https://github.com/yuxng/MDP_Tracking/blob/master/compile.m I have the OpenCV requirement already installed but am receiving some errors.

Basically the commands in octave are

```
compile
MOT_test
```

The errors I got from the `compile` command are shown below. Based on my web search plus [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896162/mex-file-building-with-octave-issue-with-wrappers) it seems like this issue of compiling the MDP Tracker remains unsolved. I have minimal experience running mex and octave so there is not much more I can do.

```
octave:4> compile
In file included from imResampleMex.cpp:7:0:
wrappers.hpp:22:24: error: ‘wrCalloc’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
 inline void* wrCalloc( size_t num, size_t size ) { return calloc(num,size); }
                        ^~~~~~
wrappers.hpp:22:24: error: ‘size_t’ was not declared in this scope
wrappers.hpp:22:36: error: ‘size_t’ was not declared in this scope
 inline void* wrCalloc( size_t num, size_t size ) { return calloc(num,size); }
                                    ^~~~~~
wrappers.hpp:22:48: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
 inline void* wrCalloc( size_t num, size_t size ) { return calloc(num,size); }
                                                ^
wrappers.hpp:23:24: error: ‘wrMalloc’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
 inline void* wrMalloc( size_t size ) { return malloc(size); }
                        ^~~~~~
wrappers.hpp:23:24: error: ‘size_t’ was not declared in this scope
wrappers.hpp: In function ‘void wrFree(void*)’:
wrappers.hpp:24:44: error: ‘free’ was not declared in this scope
 inline void wrFree( void * ptr ) { free(ptr); }
                                            ^
wrappers.hpp: At global scope:
wrappers.hpp:29:17: error: ‘size_t’ was not declared in this scope
 void* alMalloc( size_t size, int alignment ) {
                 ^~~~~~
wrappers.hpp:29:30: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
 void* alMalloc( size_t size, int alignment ) {
                              ^~~
wrappers.hpp:29:44: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
 void* alMalloc( size_t size, int alignment ) {
                                            ^
imResampleMex.cpp: In function ‘void resampleCoef(int, int, int&, int*&, int*&, T*&, int*, int)’:
imResampleMex.cpp:22:39: error: ‘alMalloc’ cannot be used as a function
   wts = (T*)alMalloc(nMax*sizeof(T),16);
                                       ^
imResampleMex.cpp:23:43: error: ‘alMalloc’ cannot be used as a function
   yas = (int*)alMalloc(nMax*sizeof(int),16);
                                           ^
imResampleMex.cpp:24:43: error: ‘alMalloc’ cannot be used as a function
   ybs = (int*)alMalloc(nMax*sizeof(int),16);
                                           ^
imResampleMex.cpp: In function ‘void resample(T*, T*, int, int, int, int, int, T)’:
imResampleMex.cpp:49:43: error: ‘alMalloc’ cannot be used as a function
   T *C = (T*) alMalloc((ha+4)*sizeof(T),16); for(y=ha; y<ha+4; y++) C[y]=0;
                                           ^
warning: mkoctfile exited with failure status
warning: called from
    mkoctfile at line 171 column 5
    mex at line 29 column 18
    compile at line 17 column 2
Compilation finished.
octave:5>
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it's got anything to do with Octave, it's your compiler that doesn't recognize the source code. What version of GCC do you have? Is it being run in C++ mode? Modify the `mex` call in `compile` to include the `-v` flag, it will show you the compile commands being executed. You should see lines starting with `g++`, if they start with `gcc`, then `mex` is using the C compiler instead of the C++ compiler.

Comment: The problem seams that to be from the source code that doesn't include the required headers. Change the line 14 from compile.m to `eval(['mex lk.cpp -include cstddef -O' include lib]);`